# Print all rows that are in specified value range based on specific column as pairs in awk

Tags: awk

Input data is sorted based on column 2 as below:

```
1   100
1   101
1   200
3   360
4   800
4   950
4   952
```

With example data desired output is:

```
1   200 3   360
4   800 4   950
4   800 4   952
```

That is, if there are lines that have values in column 2 that are in range: value2 is greater than value1+100 && value2 is less than value1+200.

My attempt was:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; PREVLOC=$2; PREVLINE=$0}{ if($2>PREVLOC+200 || $2<PREVLOC+100 {PREVLOC=$2; PREVLINE=$0;} else {print PREVLINE"\t"$0; PREVLOC=$2; PREVLINE=$0;} }' inputfile
```

Which saves the previous line and previous line column 2 into variables for comparisons. However, it does not work in all cases. With example data, it would not print the last pair. Also it wouldn't output the 800 - 950 pair if there was a line between them where second column value was e.g. 890.

Currently, I have solved the problem in completely different way in bash with:

```
`while read var1 var2; do stuff with vars in awk; done<inputfile`
```

But it's very slow. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much of an improvement this will be for you as it's still an `O(n^2)` algorithm, but it's all in awk and worth a try.

There are two passes. The `NR==FNR` block is the first pass and reads the entire file into memory (another possible issue if the file is extremely large, and I'm guessing it's pretty large if you're worried about performance). For each row we store the range to be tested against in the second pass.

The second pass goes line by line and scans for each the full set of ranges to find those that match the condition.

Be sure to note that you need to provide the input file twice on the command line when invoking awk, as shown.

```
$ cat input.txt
1   100
1   101
1   200
3   360
4   800
4   950
4   952

$ cat b.awk
# first pass, load array with ranges
NR==FNR {range[$0] = ($2 + 100) ":" ($2 + 200); next}

# Here we process the file for the second time, looping through
# all ranges for every line of input
{
    for (i in range) {
        split(range[i], r, ":")
        if ($2 > r[1] && $2 < r[2]) {
            print i, $0
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f b.awk input.txt input.txt
1   200 3   360
4   800 4   950
4   800 4   952
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. My files have ~100 k lines each and there can be up to 1,000s of them (processing them in parallel of course). Actual data is more complicated with many more fields. The only other way (besides the while loop) I came up to deal with the data was to create all possible pairs with join and then pass through awk, e.g. with example data `join -1 1 -2 1 -t $'\t' <(awk '{print 1"\t"$0}' inputfile) <(awk '{print 1"\t"$0}' inputfile) | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"} {if($5 > $3+100 && $5 < $3+200) print $2,$3,$4,$5}'`

Comment: Great!, glad its useful. The section "Two-file processing" at http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ gives a lot more explanation on this way of using awk for these kind of self-join problems (where of course the two files in question are the same file).